# Label images from text file with montage command

Tags: command-line, bash, image-processing, imagemagick

We can use this command to label each image by its name:

```
montage -label '%t' -size 512x512 "./img/*.*[120x90]" -geometry +5+5 photo.png
```

I want to label images by a list of strings, which is written in a text file. [Docs say](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#label):

> If the first character of string is @, the image label is read from a file titled by the remaining characters in the string. Labels in a file are literal, no embedded formatting characters are recognized.

But I could not use a file to provide label. I use a command like this:

```
montage -label @un.txt -size 512x512 "./img/*.*[120x90]" -geometry +5+5 photo.png
```

Above, `un.txt` is the name of text file in `./img/` path. This is a sample result:

[image: 4x4 group of images with filename @un.txt under each one]

In the result, all images are labeled with the string `@un.txt` instead of content of `un.txt`. Also I get this error in `terminal`:

```
montage.im6: improper image header `./img/un.txt' @
error/txt.c/ReadTXTImage/429
```

If I **copy** `un.txt` to the current (`.`) directory and run above command again, I will get this image (there is no label) and below error:

[image: 4x4 group of images as before, no text]

```
montage.im6: improper image header `./img/un.txt' @
error/txt.c/ReadTXTImage/429. 

montage.im6: not authorized `@un.txt' @
error/property.c/InterpretImageProperties/2959.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With attention to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39377759/1043882), I found it is probably related to the vulnerability discovered in ImageMagick ([here](https://imagetragick.com/)), so I updated my site policy file  by removing `<policy domain="path" rights="none" pattern="@*" />` line from `/etc/ImageMagick/policy.xml`. Now `montage` reads from file.